# Worklight 6.2 - App on Android device always thinks theres an update

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have built a hybrid multi-page app using Dojo mobile application and Worklight Studio.

This applications runs perfectly in the mobile simulator. However when I deploy to a real device it does not behave in the same way.

On a real device I always get a pop up saying that "an update is available". If I accept it, the app restarts and I get an Application Error dialog stating that "the connection to the server was unsuccessful (file:////data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/index.html)."

I have my android device connected to PC with USB debugging and use the Run As > android application command from Eclipse.

Logcat on first starting up:

```
10-22 13:46:25.746: D/NONE(9336): finished wlCommonInit
10-22 13:46:25.756: D/NONE(9336): after: initOptions.onSuccess
10-22 13:46:25.766: D/NONE(9336): added onPause event handler
10-22 13:46:25.776: D/NONE(9336): wlclient init success
10-22 13:46:26.256: D/CordovaLog(9336): file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/dojo.js: Line 40 : DEPRECATED: dojox/mobile/sniff Use dojo/sniff instead -- will be removed in version: 2.0
10-22 13:46:26.256: I/chromium(9336): [INFO:CONSOLE(40)] "DEPRECATED: dojox/mobile/sniff Use dojo/sniff instead -- will be removed in version: 2.0", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/dojo.js (40)
10-22 13:46:26.546: D/NONE(9336): Loading page: Application('[object Object]')
10-22 13:46:26.626: D/NONE(9336): Loading page: Login('[object Object]')
10-22 13:46:26.656: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(9336): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/_firebug/firebug.js
10-22 13:46:26.726: D/CordovaLog(9336): file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/dojo.js: Line 21 : Error: scriptError
10-22 13:46:26.726: I/chromium(9336): [INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "Error: scriptError", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/dojo.js (21)
```

Then when I hit a button on the page (which gives the update is available):

```
10-22 13:47:13.666: D/dalvikvm(9336): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 335K, 7% free 8462K/9076K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
10-22 13:47:13.666: I/dalvikvm-heap(9336): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.417MB for 124408-byte allocation
10-22 13:47:13.686: D/dalvikvm(9336): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 467K, 12% free 8116K/9200K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
10-22 13:47:13.686: D/NONE(9336): establishSSLClientAuth
10-22 13:47:13.726: D/wl.userAuthManager(9336): WLUserAuthManager.doesValidCertificateExist in WLUserAuthManager.java:144 :: doesValidCertificateExists = false
10-22 13:47:13.726: D/NONE(9336): establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
10-22 13:47:13.746: D/NONE(9336): Request [http://<ipaddress>:10080/CuramMobility/apps/services/api/CuramMobility/android/query]
10-22 13:47:13.856: D/HttpPostRequestSender(9336): HttpPostRequestSender.run in HttpPostRequestSender.java:46 :: Sending request http://<ipaddress>:10080/CuramMobility/apps/services/api/CuramMobility/android/query
10-22 13:47:14.016: D/dalvikvm(9336): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 366K, 11% free 8262K/9200K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
10-22 13:47:29.596: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(9336): WLDirectUpdateDownloader.downloadZipFile in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:100 :: Starting fresh download since app was changed on the server since last download attempt
10-22 13:47:29.656: W/HardwareRenderer(9336): Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting
10-22 13:47:29.666: W/PluginManager(9336): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLDirectUpdatePlugin.showProgressDialog blocked the main thread for 97ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
10-22 13:47:30.066: D/dalvikvm(9336): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 336K, 9% free 8437K/9200K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
10-22 13:47:32.706: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(9336): WLDirectUpdateDownloader.extractZipFile in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:204 :: Start copy files to local storage from updated zip file...
10-22 13:47:32.706: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(9336): WLDirectUpdateDownloader.extractZipFile in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:205 :: Size of zip file is 1546303
10-22 13:47:32.796: D/dalvikvm(9336): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 565K, 9% free 8380K/9200K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
10-22 13:47:32.886: D/dalvikvm(9336): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 448K, 9% free 8380K/9200K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
10-22 13:47:32.936: D/dalvikvm(9336): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 510K, 9% free 8381K/9200K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
...
...
...
10-22 13:47:33.816: D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader(9336): WLDirectUpdateDownloader.extractZipFile in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:239 :: Finish copy files to local storage from updated zip file...
10-22 13:47:33.926: D/CordovaWebView(9336): >>> loadUrl(file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/index.html)
10-22 13:47:33.926: D/PluginManager(9336): init()
10-22 13:47:33.936: D/CordovaWebView(9336): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-22 13:47:33.946: D/CordovaActivity(9336): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/index.html)
10-22 13:47:35.636: D/CordovaActivity(9336): onMessage(spinner,stop)
10-22 13:47:35.656: D/CordovaNetworkManager(9336): Connection Type: wifi
10-22 13:47:35.656: D/CordovaNetworkManager(9336): Connection Type: wifi
10-22 13:47:35.656: D/CordovaActivity(9336): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
10-22 13:47:39.246: D/CordovaLog(9336): file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/worklight/cordova.js: Line 1130 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
10-22 13:47:39.246: I/chromium(9336): [INFO:CONSOLE(1130)] "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.", source: file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (1130)
10-22 13:47:39.256: D/CordovaLog(9336): file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/worklight/cordova.js: Line 1123 : Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded
10-22 13:47:39.256: I/chromium(9336): [INFO:CONSOLE(1123)] "Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded", source: file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (1123)
10-22 13:47:40.196: D/dalvikvm(9336): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 515K, 9% free 8377K/9200K, paused 51ms, total 56ms
10-22 13:47:53.956: E/CordovaWebView(9336): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
10-22 13:47:53.956: D/CordovaWebViewClient(9336): CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/index.html
10-22 13:47:53.956: D/CordovaActivity(9336): onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-6,"url":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.CuramMobility\/files\/www\/default\/index.html","description":"The connection to the server was unsuccessful."})
10-22 13:47:54.066: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(9336): Ignore this event
10-22 13:47:54.106: D/CordovaWebViewClient(9336): onPageFinished(file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/index.html)
10-22 13:47:54.106: D/CordovaActivity(9336): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/index.html)
10-22 13:47:54.296: D/CordovaWebViewClient(9336): onPageFinished(file:///data/data/com.CuramMobility/files/www/default/index.html)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this may be a combination of 2 things.

1. For the application to "think" there is a Direct Update, this means that the web resources that were deployed to the Worklight Server and the web resources installed in the device do not match.

   Could it be that after "Run As > Run on Worklight Server" you made additional changes not in the Worklight project, but in the generated Android project and *then* selected "Run As > Android application"?
2. You need to take care of the following error, which I suspect may be what prevents the app to properly initialize:

   ```
   D/CordovaLog(9336): file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/dojo.js: Line 21 : Error: scriptError
   I/chromium(9336): [INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "Error: scriptError", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/dojo/dojo.js (21)
   ```

   [See related questions about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight%5D%5Bdojo%5D%20scripterror%20is%3Aquestion%20dojo.js%3A21).

Comment: Its certainly not 1. I build all environments and deploy to server and then run as > android application without any changes being made between these steps. This is Worklight 6.2 Foundation running in eclipse - I am not deploying to a Worklight Server per say. As for 2, line 21 in dojo.js I will keep looking at related questions.

Comment: You are. Worklight Studio embeds a Worklight Server within, but that's beside the point. See the link for how to address the second issue.

Comment: Am I using the correct process then? I do find it a bit clunky that I have to do it this way to see my changes reflected in the android app? Not sure what I could have wrong (obviously there is something).

Comment: If you're following the steps you've mentioned, you are not supposed to get any direct update notification.

Comment: Ok, found the problem - gridx directory from dojoLib was not in the APK. Line 21 in dojo.js seemed to indicate this and so I copied it over to the assets and the app now works correctly. I still get the same line 21 error in the logcat though. But can now see the app in action. Thanks.